# Spark ML Logistic Regression with Categorical Features Returns Incorrect Model

Tags: r, apache-spark, comparison, logistic-regression, glmnet

I've been doing a head-to-head comparison of Spark 1.6.2 ML's LogisticRegression with R's glmnet package (the closest analog I could find based on other forum posts).

I'm specifically looking at these two fitting packages when using categorical features. When using continuous features, results for the two packages are comparable.

For my first attempt with Spark, I used the ML Pipeline API to transform my single 21-level categorical variable (called FAC for faculty) with StringIndexer followed by OneHotEncoder to get a binary vector representation.

When I fit my models in Spark and R, I get the following sets of results (that aren't even close):

**SPARK 1.6.2 ML**

lrModel.intercept
-3.1453838659926427

lrModel.weights
[0.37664264958084287,0.697784342445422,0.4269429071484017,0.3521764371898419,0.19233585960734872,0.6708049751689226,0.49342372792676115,0.5471489576300356,0.37650628365008465,1.0447861554914701,0.5371820187662734,0.4556833133252492,0.2873530144304645,0.09916227313130375,0.1378469333986134,0.20412095883272838,0.4494641670133712,0.4499625784826652,0.489912016708041,0.5433020878341336]

**R (glmnet)**

(Intercept)    -2.79255253
facG -0.35292166
facU -0.16058275
facN  0.69187146
facY -0.06555711
facA  0.09655696
facI  0.02374558
facK -0.25373146
facX  0.31791765
facM  0.14054251
facC  0.02362977
facT  0.07407357
facP  0.09709607
facE  0.10282076
facH -0.21501281
facQ  0.19044412
facW  0.18432837
facF  0.34494177
facO  0.13707197
facV -0.14871580
facS  0.19431703

I've manually checked the glmnet results and they're correct (calculating the proportion of training samples with a particular level of the categorical feature and comparing that to the softmax prob. under the estimated model). These results do not change even when the max. no. of iterations in the optimization is set to 1000000 and the convergence tolerance is set to 1E-15. These results also do not change when the Spark LogisticRegression weights are initialized to the glmnet-estimated weights (Spark's optimizing a different cost function?).

I should say that the optimization problem is not different between these two approaches. You should be minimizing logistic loss (a convex surface) and thereby arriving at nearly the exact same answer).

Now, when I manually recode the FAC feature as a binary vector in the data file and read those binary columns as "DoubleType" (using Spark's DataFrame schema), I get very comparable results. (The order of the coefficients for the following results is different from the above results. Also the reference levels are different--"B" in the first case, "A" in the second--so the coefficients for this test should not match those from the above test.)

**SPARK 1.6.2 ML**

lrModel.intercept
-2.9530485080391378

lrModel.weights
[-0.19233467682265934,0.8524505857034615,0.09501714540028124,0.25712829253044844,0.18430675058702053,0.09317325898819705,0.4784688407322236,0.3010877381053835,0.18417033887042242,0.2346069926274015,0.2576267066227656,0.2633474197307803,0.05448893119304087,0.35096612444193326,0.3448460751810199,0.505448794876487,0.29757609104571175,0.011785058030487976,0.3548130904832268,0.15984047288368383]

**R (glmnet)**
                       s0
(Intercept) -2.9419468179
FAC_B       -0.2045928975
FAC_C        0.8402716731
FAC_E        0.0828962518
FAC_F        0.2450427806
FAC_G        0.1723424956
FAC_H       -0.1051037449
FAC_I        0.4666239456
FAC_K        0.2893153021
FAC_M        0.1724536240
FAC_N        0.2229762780
FAC_O        0.2460295934
FAC_P        0.2517981380
FAC_Q       -0.0660069035
FAC_S        0.3394729194
FAC_T        0.3334048723
FAC_U        0.4941379563
FAC_V        0.2863010635
FAC_W        0.0005482422
FAC_X        0.3436361348
FAC_Y        0.1487405173

Standardization is set to FALSE for both and no regularization is performed (you shouldn't perform it here since you're really just learning the incidence rate of each level of the feature and the binary feature columns are completely uncorrelated from one another). Also, I should mention that the 21 levels of the categorical feature range in incidence counts from ~800 to ~3500 (so this is not due to lack of data; large error in estimates).

Anyone experience this? I'm one step away from reporting this to the Spark guys.

Thanks as always for the help.

Comment: I would recommend that you ask user mailing list. However I guess you should not expect the same values as the underling optimisation used by apache spark is `SGD` (Stochastic Gradient Descent) which is a distributed implementation of gradient descent and `glmnet algorithms` use cyclical coordinate descent.

Comment: I disagree. If done correctly, since Logistic Loss is convex, Gradient Descent should converge to the global minimum, as should `glmnet`'s method, which is equivalent to Newton's Method (coordinate descent is used to find the Newton step).

Comment: Exactly Felipe. My thoughts exactly. Also, I should've mentioned that this pattern holds up whether I use L-BFGS or SGD for the optimization (you can specify which you use with Spark MLLib. To me, this is not an optimization problem. This might be a separate issue with how Spark represents categorical features.

Comment: Also Krishna, this is not a question of variability between optimization approaches. This is a simple estimation problem with (really) only one correct answer (the set of coefficients that result in the correct incidence rates of each level of the categorical feature in the dataset). The model Spark produces using the ML Pipeline transformations is just wrong.

Comment: Could we look at some of the code? Maybe it's something with the one hot encoding used or something like that.